# How to properly import only needed MDI/JS icons on my Vuetify project?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to import only the icons that I use from MDI icons because the whole MDI icon package is around 300kb. For example, it does not make sense to have on my build app 300kb for only 3 icons.

I followed Vuetify's [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons---js-svg) to implement it.

I tried importing only necessary icons for my Vuetify project, but when I run npm run build it just adds the whole package which has a size of 2.1MB (crazy right) rather than the used icons only. I guess tree shaking is not working properly.

Any idea why Vuetify's docs tutorial it is not working properly? How can I achieve this desired behavior?

I tested it by running the build on a server and the Webpack analyzer shows the same results.

Comment: Seems strange. Are you sure you are importing icons correctly - `import { mdiAccount } from '@mdi/js'` ...the format is really important

Comment: Yes I was importing same as you suggested. As I mentioned, I did it exactly like it is suggested on their docs. You can replicate this issue by creating a new vuetify project and importing one icon. Also import webpack analyzer, and you will se on Chrome devtools on the dist folder and webpack analyzer that mdi/js is being imported as a whole.

Comment: I did exactly that. Analyzer shows `mdi.js` with Parsed Size of 198 bytes

Comment: Yes you are right. It works on a fresh installation, but on my project ain't working. Weird, I have to dive deep on the reason why it includes on build time the entire package.

Comment: @VjoriHoxha did you get to the bottom of this? I have the same problem on an old angularJS project

Comment: @anorakgirl Well I have tried it with a fresh installation of Vuetify as I said and with another NuxtJS project. In both of them I have disabled default icons and used mdi/js which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**tl:dr**: have a look at your .env file and check if  *NODE_ENV=production*

Using *npm run build-prod* the three-shaking was not working.

> ```
> "build-prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode prod",
> ```

But when I use the default *npm run build* everything works fine.

Reading the [Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) docs it is saying:

> Then NODE_ENV will determine the primary mode your app is running in - development, production or test - and consequently, what kind of webpack config will be created.

So looking at my *.env.prod* file I named my *NODE_ENV=prod*. But this one indicates how to make the build. So renaming it to *production* works out.